# New layer from group

Tags: javascript, grouping, photoshop, photoshop-script

I've put a function that creates a New Group From Layers - just like the menu item.

```
new_group_from_layers("my group")

function new_group_from_layers(groupstr)
{

    // =======================================================
    var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
    var desc704 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref233 = new ActionReference();
    var idlayerSection = stringIDToTypeID( "layerSection" );
    ref233.putClass( idlayerSection );
    desc704.putReference( idnull, ref233 );
    var idFrom = charIDToTypeID( "From" );
    var ref234 = new ActionReference();
    var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
    ref234.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc704.putReference( idFrom, ref234 );
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
    var desc705 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
    desc705.putString( idNm, groupstr ); // name
    var idlayerSection = stringIDToTypeID( "layerSection" );
    desc704.putObject( idUsng, idlayerSection, desc705 );
    var idlayerSectionStart = stringIDToTypeID( "layerSectionStart" );
    desc704.putInteger( idlayerSectionStart, 14 );
    var idlayerSectionEnd = stringIDToTypeID( "layerSectionEnd" );
    desc704.putInteger( idlayerSectionEnd, 15 );
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
    desc704.putString( idNm, groupstr ); // name
    executeAction( idMk, desc704, DialogModes.NO );

}
```

My question is is there a shorter version of this not using ScriptListener code? Something like:

```
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.groupLayers.add();
layerRef.name = "my new group";
layerRef.blendMode = BlendMode.PASSTHROUGH;
```

Since selectedlayers isn't immediately accessible this makes this slightly cumbersome :(

Comment: I don't think that's possible with DOM. Any particular reason you don't want to use AM-code? Or it's just a matter of aesthetics? There're projects like [Clean SL](https://bitbucket.org/rendertom/clean-sl/src) that might help a little with the look

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I looked at the CLEAN SL code - but it's no better than the above. And I just thought it would be an obvious thing to access via the DOM

Comment: DOM covers only about 20% of what PS can do unfortunately (not mentioning that sometimes it's MUCH slower). It's just easier to get used to AM, make an external lib with all the ugly code and use your own clean version in your projects.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy That sounds like a plan!